# Копирование и вставка колонок со смещением excel c#

Tags: c#, excel

Есть код

```
excelWorksheet.Range["H1","L1"+rowcount].Copy();
excelWorksheet.Range["B1","E1"+rowcount].PasteSpecial(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPasteType.xlPasteValues);
```

но он записывает данные поверх других данных, а мне нужно чтобы он смещал данные.

Comment: Вам нужно проверять ячейки на имеющиеся в них данные и самостоятельно смещать на нужное число ячеек

Comment: а какой командой их сместить?

Comment: добавлением пустых колонок